# Split string after certain integer character pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string stored in variable `mystring`. I wanted to split the string after a  `character 4-digit-integer character` pattern i.e **(4-digit-integer)**. I suppose this can be done using Python regex.

```
mystring = 'Lorem Ipsum (2018) Amet (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)'
```

**Desired Output :**

```
splitstring = ['Lorem Ipsum (2018)', 'Amet (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)']
```

Comment: You might look at positive lookbehinds.

Comment: Do the pattern include the parenthesis, always?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind doing some filtering you could do:

```
import re

string = 'Lorem Ipsum (2018) Amet (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)'
result = [m for m in re.split('([^\d(]+\(\d{4}\))\s+', string) if m]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Lorem Ipsum (2018)', 'Amet (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)']
```

When using [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with a capturing group the result will include the group in this case `([^\d(]+\(\d{4}\))` i.e. anything that is not a number nor an open parenthesis followed exactly by four numbers surrounded by parenthesis.
No the that the following spaces `\s+` are left out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way how you could do it.

Since brackets have another meaning in REs (they are called capturing groups), you need to escape them like : `\(` for opening bracket.
Then, you can search for `(2018)` and then split the text accodringly:

```
import re
s = 'Lorem Ipsum (2018) Amet (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)'
match = re.search(r'\(\d{4}\)', s)

split_string = [ s[:match.end()], s[match.end():] ]
print(split_string) 
# ['Lorem Ipsum (2018)', ' Amet (Lorem Dolor Amet Elit)']
```